# QML ListView spacing glitch

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a simple page in my application:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Page {

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: 50
        delegate: Item {
            clip: true
            height: 50
            anchors {
                left: parent.left
                right: parent.right
            }

            Rectangle {
                color: "red"
                anchors.fill: parent
            }
            Label {
                text: index
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Sometimes, when I'm scrolling, I see spacing between rows, yet spacing is zero. I suppose it's some kind of coordinates rounding error. I tracked down  possible source of the issue -- clip: true inside delegate. If I remove it, then everything is fine.

Is it a bug of Qt, and how can I workaround it?

[image]

Comment: A red background will fix that for you ;) Other than that, there isn't much you can do, although this particular situation doesn't call for clipping. Maybe if you post your actual delegates we could think of some way to hide the artifacts. Also, performance seems to be a factor, as on a fast machine I barely see any spaces, nothing like your case.

Comment: @ddriver I see spaces when dragging outside of bounds. Yes, background could fix the issue, but I see this solution as a last resort

Comment: This is caused by the infamous qml jiggies - binding chains take time to evaluate, sometimes they don't evaluate in the same frame, causing the jiggy/elastic artifacting. In your case it is probably because the red rectangle position is not in sync with the delegate item, causing it to clip a part of the rectangle and reveal the white background behind. And no, there is nothing you can do to prevent it, at best you can hide it.

Comment: Then why do you clip, if clipping *enables* those artifacts? If you have some objects you need to clip, put them inside an Item that fills the non-clipping part of the delegate, and clip only those, while leaving the rest (e.g. the red Rectangle) unclipped...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListView's pixelAligned attribute absolutely solved the problem for me

```
ListView {
    ...
    pixelAligned: true
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only have those *glitches* when enabeling the clipping, don't use it - at least not in the delegate's root node.

```
Page {
    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: 50
        delegate: Rectangle {
            clip: false // <-- Do not clip in the delegate's root node
            height: 50
            color: "red"
            anchors {
                left: parent.left
                right: parent.right
            }
            Item {
                anchors.fill: parent
                clip: true // <-- instead you might clip in a delegate's child node
                Label {
                    text: index + 'a very long string that might be clipped at some point'
                }
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

shows at least on my computer non of those glitches.
However I would try to not clip the delegates at all, as clipping is an performance factor which might have influences especially when objects are moving (e.g. scrolling through the `ListView`)

Comment: It was already established that clipping is the cause, so this doesn't really add any substance. As of why he's clipping, I assume the question code is just an example, and his actual usage case has something that makes sense to clip.

Comment: This answer has its points to think about. In most cases clipping of root delegate's item can be avoided